# Dynamically increase the % loading of AJAX loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX loader, created using CSS.

And I m trying to increase the % loading that it shows by 10% for every 1 second, so that the user can see some progress.

I m using this `setTimeout` function to invoke it every 1 second.

Here's the function and the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpprA/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var increase = 10;
    setTimeout(function() {
        increase = increase + 10;
        $("#result").html("<div class='progress progress-striped active' style='width :300px; margin:0 auto;'><div class='bar' style='width: " + increase + "%;'></div></div>");
        if (increase == 100) {
            increase = 10;                
        }

    }, 1000);

});​
```

Comment: Why not use [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)? (`$('xxx').animate({width:'100%'}, 10000);`)

Comment: setInterval work for me!

Comment: not really an answer. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat a function call, you need `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`.

The syntax is the same, so you just have to change this token.

But in this case you're lying to the user (probably acceptable) and you're doing the work of some existing jquery functions like [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this lie! And show the user some real progress?

Comment: Not easily. The usual solution is to simply display a clearly looping indicator : it shows that a loading is in progress without trying to pretend it knows what's the actual progress. You have some [there](http://ajaxload.info/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're invoking the `setTimeout` only once. It's cool et al, but it will be called only once.

Usually, when you want to call a function every second multiple times, you use `setInterval`:

```
var int = setInterval( function() {
    // do something
}, 1000 );
```

However, `setInterval` will be run every second, even if the function inside it takes 2 seconds to run (you can see the overlap problem?).

This is why you can use the following trick, using `setTimeout`:

```
// Note that I'm naming the function in the setTimeout
var s = setTimeout( function tick() {
    // do something that takes a long time, like an ajax call

    // And finally:
    s = setTimeout( tick, 1000 );
}, 1000 );
```

Note that I'm using `var s` or `var int` to be able to use `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval` once the loading is done.

Also, it was a clever trick to use `arguments.callee` to recall the same function, but it is [now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee). So we just name the function.

An example for the ajax call:

```
var s = setTimeout( function tick() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: '',
        success: function( data ) {
            // Sup with the datas?
            s = setTimeout( tick, 1000 );
        }
    } );
}, 1000 );
```

Comment: `// do something that takes a long time, like an ajax call` . Next `setTimeout` wont wait for ajax completion

Comment: @Jashwant if you place the next call in it, it will.

Comment: Yes, its more clear now :) See your first example, it doesnt look like  , the next `setTimeout` will be called after success

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, why not `animate();` . 
Its there for a reason. It provides smoothness, easy syntax.

Also, you are appending whole markup again and again to `div#result` . It should be avoided.

Try this,

**CSS:**

```
#result > .progress{
  width :300px; 
  margin:0 auto; 
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#result').html("<div class='progress progress-striped active'><div class='bar'></div></div>");
   $('#result').find('.bar').animate({width:'100%'}, 1000); 
});​
```